# Изменение даты создания и даты модификации файла

Tags: linux, touch

Как изменить дату модификации и создания файла в Linux ?

Comment: только, пожалуйста, либо уберите из вопроса «дату создания», либо добавьте в ответ упоминание о том, что для подавляющего большинства случаев такой «даты» просто не существует: она никаким образом не фиксируется, а, следовательно, и не модифицируется.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, я не поняла. В смысле `для подавляющего большинства случаев такой «даты» просто не существует` ?

Comment: наиболее компактное из найденных за две минуты описаний ситуации: https://superuser.com/a/703927/454489 // ну а вообще: `google://unix+ctime`

Comment: Правильнее тогда будет написать изменение метаданных в которых фигурируется значение "creation time" и "modification time" ? И да, почему вы просите убрать, когда можете сделать это сами, т.к есть нужное кол-во репутации ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

В терминале вводим :

```
touch -m -a -t 199807081215.25 файл
```

либо

```
touch -mat 199807081215.25 файл
```

**Где** :

1998 - год
07 - месяц
08 - день
12 - час
15 - минута
.25 - секунда

А можно использовать ключ `-d`, который принимает строковое значение :

```
touch -mad "1998-07-08 12:15:25"
```

**Ключи** :
*-m* Дата модификации
*-a* Дата открытия файла
*-t* Отметка времени

Answer (score 1):

1. Изменяем системное время.

   `sudo date --set 10/04/2019`
2. Создаем и модифицируем файл.

   ```bsh
   touch date.txt
   touch -mat 201810141103.24 date.txt
   ```
3. Синхронизируем часы, в Arch Linux.

   `sudo timedatectl set-ntp true`
4. Результат.

   `stat date.txt`

Comment: Чем ваш ответ отличается от предыдущего?

Comment: Предыдущий не изменит дату создания.

Comment: А как изменить дату создания уже существующего файла?
В Windows можно через TotalCommander. Есть ли альтернатива в Linux?

Comment: как бы вроде также https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/806236/337543
через флаг -mat